# Why isn't SwiftUI "Toggle.onChange" firing?

Tags: swiftui, toggle, onchange

I have a toggle UI element in a List, and I need to execute code when the toggle state changes. As I understand it, that's accomplished by using a binding on the toggle, and then adding a ".onChange:of:" on the binding variable.

Done:

```
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct User : Hashable, Identifiable {
    
    var isToggled = false
    
    var id: String
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var loggedIn: Bool = false
    var loggedInSince: String?
    var isActive: Bool?
    var isAdmin: Bool?
    
}

struct ListRow: View {
 @EnvironmentObject var userListModel: UserListModel

 @Binding var user: User

 var body: some View {
     Toggle(isOn: $user.loggedIn) {
         VStack {
           Text("\(user.firstName!) \(user.lastName!)")
             if user.loggedIn {
                 Text("Logged in since \(user.loggedInSince!)")
                     .font(Font.system(size: 10))
             }
             else {
                 Text("Logged out since \(user.loggedInSince!)")
                     .font(Font.system(size: 10))
             }
         }
     }
     .disabled(self.cantLogInOut())
     .onChange(of: user.loggedIn) { value in  // THIS ISN'T WORKING, IT'S NOT GETTING CALLED
         // action...
         print(value)
         userListModel.changeLogStatus(user: user)
     }
 }
```

So, the code in the onChange ("print", "userListModel.changeLogStatus") is never called.

I'm getting this in the console:

```
2022-02-12 22:56:39.860044-0500 TimeCard[10104:4072116] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
```

I have no idea what that means, googling it isn't helpful, and when I put a Symbolic breakpoint on that error, nothing useful is shown in the debugger (it shows a stack trace that is two assembly code segments out of main.)

Comment: In your list view that contains `ListRow`, do you declare `UserListModel` with `@State`  or the required `@StateObject`? It would help if you could show how you call `ListRow`.

Comment: Is `User` a struct? You should add code of all dependent parts, otherwise we could not analyse accurately your code.

Comment: Yes, User is a struct, it's the client side of a Firebase database record. I added the struct to the code snippet above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that you can use to "...execute code when the toggle state changes."
Since you are using `userListModel.changeLogStatus(user: user)` to record the change in `loggedIn`,
there is no need to have a `@Binding var user: User` use `@State var user: User` instead.

```
class UserListModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User(isToggled: false, id: "1", firstName: "firstName-1", lastName: "lastName-1", loggedIn: false, loggedInSince: "yesterday", isActive: false, isAdmin: false),
                            User(isToggled: false, id: "2", firstName: "firstName-2", lastName: "lastName-2", loggedIn: false, loggedInSince: "yesterday", isActive: false, isAdmin: false),
                            User(isToggled: false, id: "3", firstName: "firstName-3", lastName: "lastName-3", loggedIn: false, loggedInSince: "yesterday", isActive: false, isAdmin: false)
    ]
    
    func changeLogStatus(user: User) {
        if let ndx = users.firstIndex(of: user) {
            users[ndx].loggedIn = user.loggedIn
        }
    }
}

struct User: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var isToggled = false
    var id: String
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var loggedIn: Bool = false
    var loggedInSince: String?
    var isActive: Bool?
    var isAdmin: Bool?
}

struct ListRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userListModel: UserListModel
    
    @State var user: User  // <-- use @State
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $user.loggedIn) {
            VStack {
                Text("\(user.firstName!) \(user.lastName!)")
                if user.loggedIn {
                    Text("Logged in since \(user.loggedInSince!)").font(Font.system(size: 10))
                }
                else {
                    Text("Logged in since \(user.loggedInSince!)").font(Font.system(size: 10))
                }
            }
        }
    //    .disabled(self.cantLogInOut())
        .onChange(of: user.loggedIn) { value in  // <-- THIS IS WORKING
            print("in onChange value: \(value)")
            userListModel.changeLogStatus(user: user)
        }
    }
}
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @StateObject var model = UserListModel()
        
        var body: some View {
            List(model.users) { user in
                ListRow(user: user)
            }.environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
```

You can also do the opposite, using only a `binding`, without the `EnvironmentObject` `UserListModel`, as in this code example:

```
struct ListRow: View {
    @Binding var user: User  // <-- use @Binding, no need for userListModel here
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $user.loggedIn) {
            VStack {
                Text("\(user.firstName!) \(user.lastName!)")
                if user.loggedIn {
                    Text("Logged in since \(user.loggedInSince!)").font(Font.system(size: 10))
                }
                else {
                    Text("Logged in since \(user.loggedInSince!)").font(Font.system(size: 10))
                }
            }
        }
        //.disabled(self.cantLogInOut())
        .onChange(of: user.loggedIn) { value in  // <-- THIS IS WORKING
            print("in onChange value: \(value)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = UserListModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List($model.users) { $user in   // <-- note the $ 
            ListRow(user: $user)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's done it, thanks! I went with the first option, because I need to do some other stuff when loggedIn changes.

Comment: glad it worked for you. If this answered your question, could you mark it as accepted please (with the tick mark).

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to bind the Toggle to the model but also have a side effect that also changes the model, that isn’t going to work.

You’ll have to replace the Toggle with a Button and in the handler call userListModel.changeLogStatus. And remove onChange. That way the model can stay as logged out when the log in Button is pressed and after the log in action is completed and the model is changed, body will be recomputed due to the change and the Button will be updated to show log out. You can also change @Binding var user to let user because you no longer need write access.